# Refer to an equation with multiple labels

Tags: equations, numbering, labels, ref

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}\tag{E$_{n}$}\label{E}
 f_n(x)=a
\end{equation}
```

When I write `\eqref{E}` I am referred to the equation and it is written `E_n`

My question is: how to be referred to the same equation and write for example `E_{n-1}` rather then `E_n`?

Comment: As a writer but more importantly as reader of scientific papers I beg you: please, please don't do that `;-)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Instead of writing `See Equation \eqref{E}` you can also just write `see Equation (E$_{n-1}$)`, so don't use `\eqref` at all if you don't want to use the tag. But I guess that would be very confusing for the reader?

Comment: The question/intent is ill formed, as the reference is just that, a reference to the equation, which you have given a specific (non-numeric) name to. If you wish to change the formula, then this produces a dangling reference, which does not refer to anything.

Comment: I want that when the reader click on `E_{n-1}`, he will be directed to the equation. Indeed, the equation is written as a function of `n`, and when we write `E_{n-1}` it will be clear for the reader how he can deduce it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tagindex}{\ensuremath{_{\defaulttagindex}}}
\newcommand{\defaulttagindex}{n}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\indexedref}[2][n]{%
  \begingroup\def\defaulttagindex{#1}\ref{#2}\endgroup
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\indexedeqref}[2][n]{%
  \begingroup\def\defaulttagindex{#1}\eqref{#2}\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\tag{E\tagindex}\label{E}
 f_n(x)=a
\end{equation}

We refer to~\indexedeqref{E}, but also to~\indexedeqref[n-1]{E}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For this use case you can use the command `\hyperref[label]{text}` from the `hyperref` package. It creates a (clickable) link to the `label` with the `text` being shown in the document (and not the default label text).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\tag{E$_{n}$}\label{E}
 f_n(x)=a
\end{equation}
See Equation \eqref{E}, also known as Equation (\hyperref[E]{E$_{n-1}$}).
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]